# Avoid table border split on page break while printing

Tags: html, css, printing

My content is already on the same page, that's not what the problem is. (Some other questions on SO tackle that). My issue is with borders specificaly. See how the table border splits row 43 in two.

[image]

I would like 43 to be on the next page completely. 42 should have a bottom border and 43 should have a top border. Here is what I want. (I created this in paint)

[image]

I tried `page break inside: avoid` but that doesn't work. Neither does the 4px trick works. I am in latest stable chrome. 51

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this css code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media print
{
  table { page-break-after:auto }
  tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
  td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
  thead { display:table-header-group }
  tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
....
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry bud, still the same thing happens. I am almost convinced page break css properties aren't the answer. I have tried every possible combination that I could think of.

Comment: Nope still doesn't work. Why do you think this would work specificaly? I am not even using thead or tfoot tags, page break rules dont affect tr tags, page break after auto for table is essentially useless. Why would think work?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm in the same situation

Comment: Does not work for me